# IPTables drop all input and accept ip in same statement

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

i'm having a database where i can only set the IPTables configurations by passing a firewall.conf script through an xmlrpx script. however when i sent below statement it seem to drop my connection after `:INPUT DROP`, so it wont run the `-A INPUT -s [IP] -j ACCEPT`. How can i make sure that i open the IP and close all other connections?

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT ACCEPT

-A INPUT -s [IP] -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

iptables rules are evaluated in order, so you can always have an `ACCEPT` default policy for `INPUT` and either drop or reject other packets with the last rule for `INPUT`, something like:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT ACCEPT

-A INPUT -s [IP] -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
COMMIT
```

In any case, with just the `REJECT` rule you may have a clue about what happens (perhaps a NAT in between?) instead of just silently dropping (which is in any case recommended in terms of security).

Comment: it still seem to drop my connection however if i just do `:INPUT ACCEPT
:FORWARD DROP
:OUTPUT ACCEPT

-A INPUT -s [IP] -j ACCEPT` it works fine and apply the iptables

Comment: that way you're accepting every inbound connection, same as not running iptables. You may give a try with a `-A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4` rule just before the `REJECT` rule to see why it's not being accepted, then have a look at the logs.

Comment: the problem is that this server is a closed box and i cant do anything beside setting IPTables through this conf file. so i dont have access to logs